# Can I use two different data storage in one project?

Tags: android, database

I want to use sharedpreferences in my login form, but i also want keep XAMPP as my main storage. What is the best data storage when I want to do my app in offline mode?

Comment: xampp for data store in database ? if your trying to use database try to use SQLite

Comment: Xampp... why? Why not use SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're allowed to mix and match any type of data storage you wish because none of them were designed to be in conflict with each other.

However, it's a good idea to understand what type of data storages is available for you to use, because different types of storages has different benefits and drawbacks.

SharedPreferences is a great way to store a user's preferences, or simple data with a single value. It's great for storing a user's preferences because when creating Settings, it's extremely common to use Preferences which directly reflects the values within your SharedPreferences. However, due to it's design, SharedPreferences isn't a good idea to store large amounts of data or dynamically created data.

For that, it's better to use a database and you're free to use any type of database you wish. But for offline mode, it's best to use the SQLite Database that's offered by Android by default.

However, if you do want to use XAMPP, it's not uncommon to see developers who store their full data in an online database, but cache a few data within a local database like SQlite.

Therefore, there's zero conflicts among data storage options, so mix and match to what benefits your app's design best.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any suggestion in what database can i use when I'm about to make an offline app that store a lot of images.

Comment: If your database is fully offline, then I suggest using an SQLite database with a table meant for keeping track of the filepaths for the images.

Comment: Is there a way to stay Logged In in your Sign In and Sign out form with a SQLite database?

Comment: There's a bit of a misconception here. A database does nothing besides being a storage for your data. There's no innate behavior or mechanisms that allow it to handle whether you're signed in or out. That's something you should manage for yourself. If you want to do this locally, you can create a table for storing User access times, then upon opening the app, you check the User access times and compare it with a 'kick off threshold'. If the condition isn't met and the user's credentials are still valid, then you allow him to remain logged in. If he's been off too long, then you kick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data in locally then you can use SQLite Database and yeah XAMPP is whole different thing to store data for this you need to create APIs to communicate with database.

You can also use Sharedpreferences for storing the data but Sharedpreferences will store data with the key-value pair only.

But you can use both for different different purposes for the same app

Comment: What is the best database to use when creating Login and Registration form? Thank you!

Comment: If you want data to be stored locally then go with the Room Database